# The @media is working only on locallost but not on remote server, why?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working on a PHP - MYSQL project to improve my skills. I have 2 identical copies, one on localhost and the other on a remote server. My question is:
Why the @media **work** on localhost while **not working** on the remote server?

Please note that i tried it by laptop (resizing window), iPad, Android phone. everything is OK on localhost but @media (responsive) not working on remote server.

This is the code from the style file that make the site responsive:

```
 /* The Media */
@media screen and (max-width: 760px ) {
#contentsBox {
        width: 100%;
    }
#sideBarBox {
    width:100%;
}
#footer1 {
    width: 100%;
}
#footer2 {
    width: 100%;
}
#footer3 {
    width: 100%;
}
.postTitle {
    font-size: 105%;
}

#navMobileIcon{
    display: inline-block;
}
#navMenuBox #navMenu, #navMenuBox:active #navMenu{
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #333;
    right: 20px;
    top: 80px;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    width: 50%;
}
#navMenuBox:hover #navMenu{
    display: block;
}
#navMenuItem {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#navMenu a{
    font-size: 90%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
}
#logo {
    width: 100%;
}
#widgetTitle {
    font-size: 90%;
}
.footerWidgetTitle {
    font-size: 90%;
}
}
```

Comment: is there an os difference between local + testing env?

Comment: local -> Windows 10 while Remote->Linux

Comment: Ok :) first and easiest bug to spot in this case, look for capitals/lowercase - Windows isn't case-sensitive but Linux 100% is

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@media screen
{
  @media (max-width: 760px)        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue where locally, everything looked just fine but when deployed it did not reflect the same. Still not sure technically why this happens but this is the snippet that I had originally:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { /* styling here */ }
```

The snippet that actually works for me

```
@media (max-width: 800px) { /* styling here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution by removing "screen and"
the code became like this:

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
```